# How to get valid provisioning profile to certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, provisioning, xcodebuild

Is it possible to get valid provisioning profile to certificate ?
I'm making automatically build system with **xcodebuild** and often need change provisioning.
I have got name of certificate like this **"iPhone Distribution: SERGEY KOPANEV"** and I want to get provisioning profile identifier like **4358E81F-C4B5-4743-877D-8A1DEC8C9132** to make compilation of project.
It is important because I've got a lot of project and cant change profile ID to each every time. Of course I've made global variables ad use it. But this solution can exclude one of variable!

Is it possible guys ?

Thanks,